# How do you check an if statement for a particular object?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, if-statement

I am trying to use a mouseevent.startdrag to move a particular movieclip, but I don't know how to go about checking the object in question. The code below doesn't seem to work with either *==Object(MCsquare)* or just *==MCsquare*.

```
function onStartDrag(evt:MouseEvent):void
        {
            trace(evt.target);
            if (evt.target==Object(MCsquare)) {
                evt.target.startDrag();
            }
        }
        function onStopDrag(evt:MouseEvent):void
        {
            evt.target.stopDrag();
        }
```

How can I run a check to see if the target object is MCsquare?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `getQualifiedClassName(value: *)` function of **flash.utils** package.

Comment: Thank you so much. I just ran a check of the getQualifiedClassName for the evt.target against that of MCsquare and it worked, thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

Is MCsquare a class? If so, you can use the "is" operator.

```
if(evt.target is MCsquare)
```

Will return true if the class is MCsquare.